# Best method to create a select option in a JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I've been teaching myself how to create Java servlets with JSPs and I think I've more or less avoided picking up any bad habits so far. However, I haven't really been able to find anything useful on this subject.

If I wanted to create a select option in my JSP with static options - such as separate drop downs to create a month, day, year selection - how should I go about doing this?

I'm assuming simply hardcoding it into the JSP with HTML is not ideal. The other methods that come to mind is using JSTL to say loop through 1 and 31 to create the options for the day, and I read briefly about using a Java bean to contain the data and printing the data out that way. Although I don't know much about jQuery, it looks like that could be used to construct the select option as well.

Is there an accepted method of doing this, or conversely are there methods that I should definitely avoid? As I'm learning about servlets and JSPs, I'd like to avoid doing things the wrong way.

Comment: It depends on data source mate. If it is dynamic, say from `database` you could fetch a list and fill up the options on page loading. Otherwise you can go for `enumeration type` where, you can have your static data and load it when required. But in case of static data which does not require frequent change, you can hardcode as well.

Comment: It's not dynamic. Well, I do have a few that are dynamic in my servlet, but I'm already pulling those from a database and outputting them correctly in the JSP. I'm interested in one that's static, like the date example I used. For hardcoding, should I use JSTL, jQuery, or is even just writing it in hard HTML acceptable? What's the common practice?

Comment: Normally folks do not separete a date field they just use a datepicker component. See one here using jquery  http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that. Not really familiar with jQuery, so thanks.

I guess a better example than would be say a selection of colors and numbers. If I wanted a list of a dozen colors and a number between 1 and 10, what's the preferred method of constructing these?

Comment: Just plain and simple HTML but if those components would repeat thenselves on many pages of your project then you should create a component using perhaps JSTL with custom tags. Take a look here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm and here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm

Comment: Yeah, I suppose I should have mentioned that the element would be used multiple times. Thanks for the links, didn't really think about creating custom JSP tags.